# Spring Integration RabbitMQ + Consume Internal events from amq.rabbitmq.event topic exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want to consume internal events that are published to the  **amq.rabbitmq.event** such as **client.connected, client.disconnected**.

Below is my Spring Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost"
                               username="guest" password="guest"/>

    <rabbit:queue name="amqp.rabbitmq.events.client.connections.created"
                  id="amqp.rabbitmq.events.client.connections.created"
                  auto-delete="true" durable="false"/>

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" auto-startup="true"/>

    <rabbit:topic-exchange id="amq.rabbitmq.event" name="amq.rabbitmq.event" durable="true">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="amqp.rabbitmq.events.client.connections.created" pattern="connection.created">
            </rabbit:binding>
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:topic-exchange>

    <bean id="asyncListener" class="com.example.rabbitmq.com.tp.spring.amqp.rabbit.SpringAMQPRabbitAyncListener"/>
    <rabbit:listener-container id="myListenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory">
        <rabbit:listener ref="asyncListener" queue-names="amqp.rabbitmq.events.client.connections.created"/>
    </rabbit:listener-container>
```

With the above configuration i am getting exception: **Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'internal' for exchange 'amq.rabbitmq.log' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=40, method-id=10)**

Not only the amq.rabbitmq.events topic, but pointing other internal topic also yields same exception.

Exception:

```
2017-02-10 06:59:15.908 ERROR 18602 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'internal' for exchange 'amq.rabbitmq.log' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=40, method-id=10)
2017-02-10 06:59:15.915 ERROR 18602 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:113) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1461) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:500) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$11.onCreate(RabbitAdmin.java:419) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:33) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:553) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1114) [spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95) [spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1333) [spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.exchangeDeclare(ChannelN.java:763) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.exchangeDeclare(AutorecoveringChannel.java:237) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:917) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.exchangeDeclare(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareExchanges(RabbitAdmin.java:554) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.access$000(RabbitAdmin.java:66) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$12.doInRabbit(RabbitAdmin.java:503) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1455) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'internal' for exchange 'amq.rabbitmq.log' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=40, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'internal' for exchange 'amq.rabbitmq.log' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=40, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572) ~[amqp-client-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    ... 1 common frames omitted

2017-02-10 06:59:15.922  WARN 18602 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:amqp.rabbitmq.events.client.connections.created
2017-02-10 06:59:15.923  WARN 18602 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Queue declaration failed; retries left=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `internal` attribute for you on the `:topic-exchange` which is `false` by default.

On the other hand there is `auto-declare` to try do not declare it at all. Just because that exchange is there on Broker anyway.

Comment: After modifying the xml as suggested, i am able to consume the message from the internal exchange. Update the xml in the question.

Comment: I don't see reason in this comment. If this answers to your problem, just accepts it and that's all. Otherwise provide useful info what's wrong